# Footnote marker placement in heading of theorem/definition/etc.

Tags: footnotes, theorems, amsthm

I have a definition, and a footnote which refers to the whole definition.  So I’d ideally like an output looking something like:

> **Definition 1.5<sup>3</sup>.**   A footnote is a small aside, usually placed at the bottom of a page and marked by a tag in the main text.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>3</sup>Some people think that footnotes are bad style.

Is there a good way to get this placement of the footnote marker?  Neither of the following comes out right (for obvious reasons):

`\begin{definition}\footnote{Footnote text.} We define \ldots`

`\begin{definition}[\footnote{Footnote text.}] We define \ldots`

I’m using `amsthm`, but answers for without that would be interesting too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the definition of `\thetheorem` inside a group so as to include the desired footnote. (I use the `\apptocmd` command of the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package to amend the definition without looking up the particulars of the original.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\apptocmd{\thetheorem}{\protect\footnote{A footnote.}}{}{}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\endgroup

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Interestingly, this only seems to work with `amsthm`.

Comment: Redefining `\thetheorem` won't work well with the `\label`/`\ref` mechanism as the footnote will appear at each reference. You can get around this by replacing `\protect\footnote{A footnote.}` by `\unless\ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect\protect\footnote{A footnote.}\fi`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the previous answer, so let me add the following as an answer instead.

I found what Philippe Goutet said in the comment to lockstep's answer to be true, namely that a footnote appears in references to the theorem too. Perhaps it is obvious to others how to implement Philippe's fix, but it wasn't to me: it seems that one also needs to add something like `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` somewhere. The following version of lockstep's answer thus works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\thetheorem}{\unless\ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect\protect\footnote{A footnote.}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{theorem}\label{mainthm}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\endgroup

Compare the following to Theorem \ref{mainthm}.

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Footnote directly after theorem number, without appearing in references]

I don't know if there is some better place to insert the commands, but the above seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are right with `\makeatletter...\makeatother`. Perhaps you could add a screen shot of the output too?

Comment: Is there a way to define an environment which takes the footnote as an argument , so that one doesn't need to cut and paste all that code every time?