# How can I add a footnote to a theorem header?

Tags: footnotes, ntheorem

I would like to add a footnote to a theorem ("Korollar" in the minimal-not-working-examples below) that explains in simple words what the theorem states in exact (but more difficult) words. So the footnote should be after the number.

Please note that I only need this for one or two theorems. For the rest (about 20) I don't need it. So a solution should not change the behaviour of those other theorems.

## What I've tried

### Try 1

This one is from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6508/5645), but the footnote does not appear at all:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}

\theoremstyle{break}
\setlength\theoremindent{0.7cm}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-0.7cm\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont} % nicht mehr kursiv

\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollar}[satz]{Korollar}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \apptocmd{\thetheorem}{\protect\footnote{Im Grunde wird die Äquivalenz von Stetigkeit im Sinne der Analysis und Topologie auf metrischen Räumen gezeigt.}}{}{}
    \begin{korollar}
        Seien $X, Y$ metrische Räume und $f: X \rightarrow Y$ eine Abbildung.

        Dann gilt: $f$ ist stetig $\Leftrightarrow$ zu jedem $x \in X$ und jedem
        $\varepsilon > 0$ gibt es $\delta(x, \varepsilon) > 0$, sodass für
        alle $y \in X$ mit $d(x,y) < \delta $ gilt 
        $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$.
    \end{korollar}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

### Try 2

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}

\theoremstyle{break}
\setlength\theoremindent{0.7cm}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-0.7cm\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont} % nicht mehr kursiv

\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollar}[satz]{Korollar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{korollar}\footnote{Im Grunde wird die Äquivalenz von Stetigkeit im Sinne der Analysis und Topologie auf metrischen Räumen gezeigt.}
        Seien $X, Y$ metrische Räume und $f: X \rightarrow Y$ eine Abbildung.

        Dann gilt: $f$ ist stetig $\Leftrightarrow$ zu jedem $x \in X$ und jedem
        $\varepsilon > 0$ gibt es $\delta(x, \varepsilon) > 0$, sodass für
        alle $y \in X$ mit $d(x,y) < \delta $ gilt 
        $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$.
    \end{korollar}
\end{document}
```

### Try 3

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}

\theoremstyle{break}
\setlength\theoremindent{0.7cm}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-0.7cm\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont} % nicht mehr kursiv

\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollar}[satz]{Korollar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{korollar}[\footnote{Im Grunde wird die Äquivalenz von Stetigkeit im Sinne der Analysis und Topologie auf metrischen Räumen gezeigt.}]
        Seien $X, Y$ metrische Räume und $f: X \rightarrow Y$ eine Abbildung.

        Dann gilt: $f$ ist stetig $\Leftrightarrow$ zu jedem $x \in X$ und jedem
        $\varepsilon > 0$ gibt es $\delta(x, \varepsilon) > 0$, sodass für
        alle $y \in X$ mit $d(x,y) < \delta $ gilt 
        $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$.
    \end{korollar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to footnote the header and not the commentary text before the corollary?

Comment: I thought about this. But I think with a footnote, people will be more likely to recognize it when reading (and trying to understand) the theorem. Also, it feels right to use a footnote. I can't explain why, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily hijack the theorem separator/punctuation that comes immediately after the theorem number. In your case it is empty, but in any case you can make it include a command `\thmfoot` which you can redefine when needed.  Now use a combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` to get the footnote:

[image: Sample theorem]

[image: Sample foot]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand{\thmfoot}{}

\theoremstyle{break}
\setlength\theoremindent{0.7cm}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-0.7cm\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont} % nicht mehr kursiv
\theoremseparator{\thmfoot}

\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollar}[satz]{Korollar}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thmfoot}{\footnotemark}
\begin{korollar}
  \footnotetext[\thefootnote]{Im Grunde wird die Äquivalenz
  von Stetigkeit im Sinne der Analysis und Topologie auf metrischen
  Räumen gezeigt.}
  Seien $X, Y$ metrische Räume und $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ eine
  Abbildung.

  Dann gilt: $f$ ist stetig $\Leftrightarrow$ zu jedem $x \in X$ und
  jedem $\varepsilon > 0$ gibt es $\delta(x, \varepsilon) > 0$, sodass
  für alle $y \in X$ mit $d(x,y) < \delta $ gilt $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) <
  \varepsilon$.
\end{korollar}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```