# thmtools: Footnotes in theorem names and notes

Tags: footnotes, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I am using the `thmtools` package as a frontend to `amsthm` to typeset various types of theorems. Sometimes I feel the need to put a footnote either directly at the theorem name or inside the theorem note.

To be preicse, when this is my document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{mytheorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{mytheorem}[Some reference]
    This statement is true.
\end{mytheorem}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to put footnotes at the positions indicated here:
[image: mockup for footnotes in thmtools]

For position 1, the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200445/35179) for `amsthm` is working fine with `thmtools` when changing `\thetheorem` to `\themytheorem`.

For position 2 there is no problem when just using `amsthm` without `thmtools`: something like `\begin{mytheorem}[Some reference\footnotemark]` followed by a `\footnotetext{...}` nearby just works. However, when using `thmtools` this results in the following error:

```
! Argument of \@begintheorem has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147113/how-can-i-add-a-footnote-to-a-theorem-header

Answer (score 6):

Of course, after carefully phrasing a question and preparing a MWE, I figured out how to achieve the desired result.

This seems to be the common problem of a [fragile command in a moving argument](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-extrabrace.html) and using `\protect` fixes that.

So the following works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{mytheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}[Some reference\protect\footnotemark]
    \footnotetext{This is a footnote}
    This statement is true.
\end{mytheorem}
\end{document}
```